# Attempting to allocate already allocated variable

Tags: memory-management, fortran

I am having a problem with the following routine beacuse I get 
the Fortran runtime error: `Attempting to allocate already allocated variable 'sb'`. The function seems good to me but obviously the compiler is not liking it. When can it happen that allocate is called twice?

The problem occurs when I call the function for the second time in my program.

Here is my call

```
sb = srepl (sa, "s/duda/duda:/g")
sc = srepl (sb, "s/ //g")
```

This s the funtion

```
Function srepl (sa, test, psutl) Result (sb)

Character (Len=:), Allocatable :: sb
Character (Len=*), Intent (In) :: sa
Character (Len=*), Intent (In), Optional :: test

Integer :: k
Character (Len=65) :: s, a, b, c, d

If (Present (psutl)) Then
  Allocate (Character (Len=Len_trim(sa)) :: sb)
  Return
End If

If (get (k) /= 3) Then
  Allocate (Character (Len=Len_trim(sa)) :: sb)
  sb = Trim (sa) 
  Return
End If

If (valid (test, a)) Then

  s = Trim (a)

Else If (project (test, b)) Then

  s = Trim (b)

Else

  If (project (sa, c, d) Then
    s = Trim (c)
  Else
    s = Trim (d) 
  End If

End If 

Allocate (Character (Len=Len_trim(s)) :: sb)
sb = Trim (s)

End Function srepl
```

Comment: If this is your full code then I'll note that you may reference lots of local variables without first defining them: that could easily cause strange problems.  As stated in comments elesewhere, you also don't need to do these explicit allocations.

Comment: I do think everything is defined. When one uses allocate, a deallocate should not be called, am I right? I will be sticking with automatic allocation. Promarily not because it solves my problem, but rather because automatic allocation should be favoured when possible.

Comment: They could be, it's just that I don't see how `get`, `valid` and `project` work.

Comment: I can create a small program to replicate the problem. Perhaps I missed some variable and have not noticed.

Comment: Further, by the time we get to the reference of `valid` we know that `test` isn't present.  `a` must also be `intent(out)` or else it's referenced before being defined: so you've a function reference with one optional argument not present and another other `intent(out)` which is returning a logical result.  This sounds strange.  That is, I think your code is dodgy and there's a problem we haven't the information to detect.

Comment: I shortened things down. Looking at it again it is a bit dodgy, but only wanted to highlight the allocate problem.

Comment: That's fair enough, but just be careful that if you're doing bad referencing (such as in `valid` the first dummy argument isn't `optional` or is referenced) then that could manifest in strange errors later on.  I could, of course, also be missing something very obvious with your allocations...

Comment: I will have a deeper study of my code on the direction you mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

You should always deallocate an allocated array before performing another memory allocation. When you want to allocate another memory, beforehand you could always test whether a variable already has memory allocated, and if it is true, then deallocate it first.

For example, I have a variable `myvar` that is allocatable, I could test it with the function `Allocated()`, which will return true if `myvar` has allocated memory, false otherwise.

```
ALLOCATE( myvar(10) )

IF( ALLOCATED(myvar) )  DEALLOCATE( myvar )
```

Or you could also:

```
IF( .NOT. ALLOCATED( myvar ) ) ALLOCATE( myvar(10) )
```

In which the second case will allocate memory only when it is empty.

Comment: I need to allocate as the output from the function is a string where its length changes according to the length of another.

Comment: @Charles As in you have "hello" and you want to increase its length but also keep its current data like "hello      " ?

Comment: It might get replaced by something else, that's why I allocate the output with the length of `s`. The problem happens when I call the function a second time in the program.

Comment: An interesting thing is that when I comment out the `allocate` calls to `sb` everything works fine. Fortran must be using automatic allocation, however never gets the `already allocated` problem on the second call.

Comment: I am using gfortran 5.0

Comment: @Charles You are probably seeing Fortran 2003 automatic reallocation of the lhs side of assignments (if the lhs is allocatable). Key there is *reallocation* , if you want to explicitly reallocate like you are, you need to deallocate first, then allocate again.

Comment: @Charles values of internal variables are also preserved through functions calls with the SAVE attribute, which may or may not be the case. Unfortunately i cant test it right now.

Comment: I have seen examples to output arrays from functions using an allocatable result, and I never seen anyone using deallocate. I am going to use automatic allocation. However I am wondering whether this is a gfortran 5.0 bug.

Comment: @Charles No, this is not a compiler bug. If you call `allocate` on anything than it must be not currently allocated. If it is, you must deallocate it. Automatic reallocation on assignment is something else than `allocate()` and follows different rules.

Comment: Attempting to `allocate` an allocated allocatable variable is indeed bad, but can you explain in this answer how we get to a point where `sb` is already allocated before an allocation attempt?

Comment: The problem surfaces when I call the function a second time.